# twilio click to call Java Servlet - not working

Tags: java, servlets, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I have tried to setup twilio click to call java Servlet example by following the below url.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/java/servlets

However, when I am providing the phone number to call (it's an India number starts with +91), no call is coming to that mobile.

1. The number which I am calling has been verified in twilio account. It can receive twilio sms.
2. No error is coming back from twilio. But still I am not getting any call. I have verified by providing another phone number (of another service provider) ...but same result.
3. twilio console shows the call has happened for 15 seconds..in each case. But in none of the case I have got any ring in my phone.
4. I am am not also getting any call in the callback url (/connect ) from twilio  which I am supposed to get after the call is connected...that is twilio is supposed to call back my url.
5. I have also provided a permission in the following place to for voice call in India.

https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions

Thanks in advance
SR

Answer (score 0):

Kevin from Twilio here.

It sounds like there may be something here worth investigating with support. If you could, please send an e-mail to help@twilio.com with this description. If you also provide your Account SID and if possible a call SID for the calls you are debugging in the console, that should help debug the issue more quickly.

Thanks, and sorry you're having troubles.

Comment: Thanks for offering help....In the meantime I have rewritten the full code using Twilio 6.3.0 API instead of Twilio 7.0.0-rc-25 Java API which is there in example. And now the calls are coming. So, probably there is some issue in Twilio 7.0.0-rc-25 Java API.